# Capturing rendering events in React

Tags: reactjs, events, rendering

I am using the react table library to make a table, but to work with my current project I am using manual pagination. I want to know if I can capture the event when my table re-renders when new data is added. If I can capture when the table component is being rendered then I have the context of when to trigger a call to grab a variable from Grafana.

Specifically I need to know when the react table is constructed with new data so I can handle pagination accordingly in a different part of the code. What is the best way to do this?